# Express js external javascript file not loading

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I use an express app to serve an static pre-compiled jade file. which includes a external javascript file. but its not loaded while the page gets loaded. but i can access the javascript by the express static/public url. Why its not loading on the html?

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    sass = require('node-sass');

var app = express();

/* default configurations */
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

/* routes */
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World');
});

app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index.html');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**index.html**

```
  <body>
    <script type="text/javscript" src="/scripts/site.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function()  {
        Site.View.init();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
```

**site.js**

```
var Site = Site || {};
Site.View = {
  init : function() { alert('view'); }
};
```

When i open the page in browser i get **ReferenceError: Site is not defined**

Thanks.

Comment: My first guess is that your engine is not initializing. You may want to look at how you are implementing app.engine. Almost all failures in node.js are from something simple. like missing a parameter or parenthesis.

Comment: @Brian i tried multiple ways even i tried `res.sendfile('[path_to_the_file]profile.html')` but still the js is not loaded.

Comment: Interesting. If you find this, I would love to see why you are getting this. I have always used a variant of the sample http://nodejs.org/ webserver, and ran everything up that way.

Comment: Can you show the directory structure of your project/app and where exactly `index.html` and `site.js` are in that structure?

Answer (score 1):

Add `app.use('/public/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/scripts')));` to app.js, in order to indicate the subfolders of the pulic folder;

If it still not works, change `src="/scripts/site.js"` to `src="/public/scripts/site.js"`;

Answer (score 0):

site.js must be inside public/scripts from your root directory.

I am not sure but both views and express static pages are gone to public directory in your code.
Use default configuration as:
`app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Answer (score 0):

You may also add a route for it like this:

```
app.get('scripts/site.js', function(req, res){
    res.send('./scripts/site.js');
}
```